# Uploading a file less than 5MB through using multipart upload api to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

As per the Amazon multipart upload documentation the Each part must be at least 5 MB in size, except the last part.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html

Question is how do I upload a file less than 5MB through multipart upload  api to AWS S3 bucket. The reason I am asking this that I want to use multipart upload API for all files when uploading to S3

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can still upload it using multipart upload, the same as you would a larger file... but you have to upload it with only one part.

The rule enforced by S3 is that all parts except the last part must be >= 5MB.  If the first part is also the last part, this rule isn't violated and S3 accepts the small file as a multipart upload.

Comment: Does this mean, that I can only upload 1 file per multipart uploadId? Is there a way to have more than one parts below 5MB for one UploadId?

Comment: @MarcJohnson multipart upload is intended for uploading one single file, usually a large one, as multiple independent parts. The parts are uploaded in different HTTP transactions and can be sent in any order (including in parallel) and are retryable if errors (like timeouts or connection loss) occur. Once all the parts are in, the Complete operation validates them and combines them into one single object.  All of the parts except the last one must be at least 5 MB in size.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can I use Multipart Upload across the AWS accounts?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but you can use the Multipart Upload API in the same ways you can use other S3 API actions.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sorry for not being clear, I was asking if it is possible to read from one bucket and write to another in Multipart upload. I'm not very sure about it because of the way **CopyPartRequest** is being created.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra yes, it's just like PUT+Copy -- you need a single set of credentials with read access to the source object and write access to the target object.  As long as you have credentials from one account with both permissions properly granted, it will work correctly, including cross-account.