# Copy list of files from S3 bucket to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cp

Is there a way I could copy a list of files from one S3 bucket to another? Both S3 buckets are in the same AWS account. I am able to copy a single file at a time using the aws cli command:

```
     aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/file.txt s3://target-bucket/file.txt
```

However I have 1000+ files to copy. I do not want to copy all files in the source bucket so I am not able to utilize the sync command. Is there a way to call a file with the list of file names that needs to be copied to automate this process?

Comment: Not really an answer, but perhaps interesting to you. You can generate bucket listings very cheap using inventory management on the bucket. If you have millions of files this can save considerable money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approaching this problem from the Python aspect, you can run a Python script that does it for you. Since you have a lot of files, it might take a while but should get the job done. Save the following code in a file with `.py` extension and run it. You might need to run `pip install boto3` beforehand in your terminal in case you don't already have it.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
mybucket = s3.Bucket('oldBucket')
list_of_files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
for obj in mybucket.objects.all():
    if obj.key in list_of_files:
        s3.Object('newBucket', obj.key).put(Body=obj.get()["Body"].read())
```

Comment: Will this script cop all files in the 'oldbucket' or am I able to use a list to tell this script exactly the list of files to copy?

Comment: This copies all of them. You can add an if statement inside the for loop. I'll edit so that it copies the list.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It seems as though this script will only copy files that are less than 5 GB. Is there a way to initiate the multipart copy needed for larger files?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839387/uploading-a-file-less-than-5mb-through-using-multipart-upload-api-to-aws-s3-buck) out

Answer (score 3):

You can use the  `--exclude` and `--include` filters and as well use the `--recursive` flag in `s3 cp` command to copy multiple files

Following is an example

```
aws s3 cp /tmp/foo/ s3://bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg"
```

For more details [click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the AWS CLI, you could use `cp` in a loop over a file containing the names of the files you want to copy:

```
while read FNAME
do
  aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/$FNAME s3://target-bucket/$FNAME
done < file_list.csv
```

I've done this for a few hundred files. It's not efficient because you have to make a request for each file.

A better way would be to use the `--include` argument multiple times in one `cp` line. If you could generate all those arguments in the shell from a list of files you would effectively have

```
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/ s3://target-bucket/ --exclude "*" --include "somefile.txt" --include "someotherfile.jpg" --include "another.json" ...
```

I'll let someone more skilled figure out how to script that.