# What is the best way to copy multiple files from one bucket to another in AWS S3?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a list of filenames in a csv file that I want to copy to a new bucket. Im thinking of looping through each of the filenames and use "aws cp" to copy but I don't think it is the best way to do it and I'm also worried about the bills that Amazon might charge me (not really sure if they do charge for this, please let me know) especially if I have to do it 16K times. Is there any other way I can do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are various solutions on the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654936/copy-list-of-files-from-s3-bucket-to-s3-bucket

Comment: Yes, AWS will bill you for that, why shouldn't they? At least if you are outside the free tier. And doing an `aws cp` or a higher level copy operation all do the same thing and are basically the only viable option. What ***exactly*** are you worried about?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inputs. I already solved my problem. After some more reading, I found out that S3 has this Batch Operations feature which was perfect in my situation.